# HTML/JavaScript Drag & Drop - is it possible to make the ghost image *NOT* look 'washed out'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on some drag and drop features for an application, and while there are a lot of things that can be done with the 'ghost images' that get drug from one spot to another, they always look a little 'washed out' - hence the name ghost image.  Is it possible to make these have the same depth of color as the original?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the native drag and drop functionality, or jQuery UI's draggable/droppable functionality?

Comment: @GregL - Native, but I'm not opposed to using jQuery or another library if that makes more sense.  I can do everything I want with the HTML5 approach, but I would prefer to avoid the washed out look of the object while it is being moved.

Answer (score 3):

Not if you're using the builtin drag & drop the browser provides. Most javascript libraries allow you to completely style the dragged item.

Comment: Thanks - I took a look at the jQuery site and it looks like it will do what I need and looks better.  Plus, I like the demos that show how to 'snap' dragged items into place.